# Can't change name of Worksheet using If statement

Tags: vba, excel

I want to change names of Worksheet depends on file I have. It should have either "File1" or "File2" worksheet.But I am getting an error "Out of range" when I am trying to use changed names of worksheets so it means that code inside if statement doesn't work, please help me out with this.

```
Dim wsSheet As Worksheet
Dim wsSheet2 As Worksheet
On Error Resume Next
Set wsSheet = Sheets("File1")
Set wsSheet2 = Sheets("File2")
On Error GoTo 0
If Not wsSheet Is Nothing Then
Sheets("Sheet1").Name = "Sheet1ChangedFile1"
Sheets("Sheet2").Name = "Sheet2ChangedFile1"
Else
If Not wsSheet2 Is Nothing Then
Sheets("Sheet1").Name = "Sheet1ChangedFile2"
Sheets("Sheet2").Name = "Sheet2ChangedFile2"
End If
End If

Sheets("Sheet1ChangedFile2").Select 'Here I get an error
```

Comment: My guess is that wsSheet2 is Nothing is true. So you never hit the second if statement

Comment: but the thing is I have this worksheet, and it works for the first if statement

Comment: The first `If` sets the Sheet1's name to Sheet1Changed**File1**. You cannot try to select Sheet1Changed**File2** if Sheet1 has been renamed to Sheet1Changed**File1**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the Else statement, if you fulfill the first if statement, you never reach the else part, so use this instead:

```
Dim wsSheet As Worksheet
Dim wsSheet2 As Worksheet
On Error Resume Next
Set wsSheet = Sheets("File1")
Set wsSheet2 = Sheets("File2")
On Error GoTo 0
If Not wsSheet Is Nothing Then
Sheets("Sheet1").Name = "Sheet1ChangedFile1"
Sheets("Sheet2").Name = "Sheet2ChangedFile1"
End If 'Changed the Else to End If
If Not wsSheet2 Is Nothing Then
Sheets("Sheet1").Name = "Sheet1ChangedFile2"
Sheets("Sheet2").Name = "Sheet2ChangedFile2"
End If

Sheets("Sheet1ChangedFile2").Select
```